# How OK is it to post an answer on a (maybe) duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

I've had this doubt from time to time, in a few similar scenarios. Typically :

I see pop a new question which seems to be some variation on a classic problem, to which I happen to know how to usefully answer. There is probably a very old and famous question/answer around here answering the general case in which this specific question fits more or less.

At this point, I often make a search for existing questions, but not always, and sometimes they just don't look similar enough to me.

**Let's state the point clearly though : If it *is* a near exact duplicate with a directly usable accepted answer, I don't answer and just vote to close with a link to the old question**

When I have the impression that I could write something short and clear to answer the immediate need, I post an answer. Then sometimes...

...either it's not marked as duplicate as such (maybe for lack of attention) even if it's quite similar.

...or after a few close votes the question is marked as duplicate and properly hold on, like it should.

**In these two cases, is it a bad idea to actually answer these questions? Should I just vote for closing? Or do both?**

---

Note : Sometimes, I do **both**. I answer *and* vote for closing as duplicate. I've always thought it was not too bad of a compromise : adressing the specific situation for a (potential) beginner who could struggle adapting to an even slightly different context than his, and linking duplicates. It can't hurt I guess, if I understood right that we keep duplicates around rather than deleting them, among other things, for better SEO.

Comment: IMO, if you have tried your best to find a duplicate but couldn't, there's little harm in posting an answer. Perhaps you were wrong in your assumption that a duplicate exists, or the duplicate clearly isn't as easy to find as it should be.

Comment: Somewhat related, but about obvious dups: [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](/q/252009/11107541)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a question is closed or *should be closed*, it should not be answered. Closing a question means it is not suitable to be answered in its current form, or is a duplicate of another question. In the case of a duplicate, it's easier to maintain if all answers are in one place. Either way, it should not be answered.

If the question is a duplicate but has not been closed yet, *do not answer it*. Vote to close as duplicate of the other question.

If the question is similar to another question but not a duplicate, leave a comment and an answer. You can use a link to the related question in your answer if necessary.

Comment: I get the general sense of your answer, but I'm not quite sure of what you mean by "easier to maintain".

Comment: @RomainValeri if the answers to the question became outdated, it would be a lot easier to deal with if all answers were on one question instead of multiple. Also, it's easier to browse through all the answers at once if they're all kept in one place. That's what I mean by 'easier to maintain'.

Comment: Fair enough. Point taken, I'll be more systematic in my search for duplicates beforehand, and refrain from posting answers if I found anything relevant enough.

Comment: No, a question that is only quite similar is [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123991/397360) in fact a duplicate. OP's question is explicit that he's considering duplicates to be questions that are "quite similar."

Comment: @AlexHarvey Similar but different questions are *often* duplicates.  What matters is whether the differences *are relevant to the answer*.  Sometimes the slight differences in a question change what the answer is.  Often they don't.

Comment: @Servy, "different questions" are by definition not "duplicates". What is the square root of 16? What is 2 + 2? Very different questions can have the same answer too. The key here is you should be certain one way or the other, and similiar != duplicate.

Comment: @AlexHarvey "2" is a terrible answer to either question.  A *proper* answer to either question wouldn't answer the other (in addition to the fact that obviously neither question would be appropriate here).  "Different questions" are *frequently* duplicates, when those differences are irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy, I am sure we can agree that sometimes the same question is asked in a different way, and sometimes two different questions are merely quite similar, and the key is being able to distinguish these two cases with certainty.

Comment: @AlexHarvey No, they key is whether you're reasonably confident that the answers to one question provide a high quality answer to another, in which case, they're duplicates, even if there are differences that end up not preventing the answer from being a quality answer to both questions.

Comment: @Servy, what's wrong with deferring judgement on a matter until you're certain? Saying "reasonably confident" is good enough seems to be a recipe for allowing people to make somewhat arbitrary decisions.

Comment: @AlexHarvey "reasonably confident" and "arbitrary" are not at all the same.  If you required certainty before doing anything then you'd never do anything ever.  Certainty is a bar that's literally impossible to meet.

Comment: Well, for me, I generally use "reasonably confident" to mean I still have some doubt, and I could spend more time and become certain. I guess we're just using different words to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple:

- If you are sure that a question is an exact duplicate of another one, then vote-to-close and don't answer it.
- If you investigated and found a question that is merely "quite similar", then you should *not* vote to close, and you should post an answer. I also generally link to the related question.

Being unsure suggests a lack of confidence in your understanding of the questions. If so, I probably would make 100% sure I do understand the questions before posting an answer.

And if you are unsure, then you absolutely should not vote-to-close.

Comment: About the lack of confidence : yes, sometimes it's a technical doubt, in which case I research it further before answering. However, on occasions it's not that, but rather lack of info in the question itself. OP intentions not stated, context not given, it's often difficult to know if the existing question/answers will be useful or must be adapted.

Comment: It sounds like the real issue is the question is simply not clear, and that's why you can't tell if it's a duplicate. I would suggest leaving a comment requesting both clarification of the question and a link to the possible duplicate. The OP should then either agree that their question is a duplicate, or clarify it, to make it clearer why it isn't.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Not all posters actually answer comments but it's certainly an excellent first step for these situations.